# CSS how to align different size images with text inside row?

Tags: css, svg

Need to align four different height (beetween 160-180px) `svg` images with text under them.
Images should be placed in line at sight and I don't know how to make strict align short text under them in one line like on screenshot.

Thanks!

[image]

UPD: Sorry for inconvinient information, thought that this question is quite typical for those who know css good.
Here is my html and css. Also I'm using `bootstrap` rows.

```
    <div class="did-you-know">
    <div class="row items">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
            <div class="icon">
                <img src="/img/mswa/inline-wa.svg"/>
            </div>
            <div class="title text-poppins">
                <p>We’re from WA</p>
                <p>{like you!}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
            <div class="icon">
                <img src="/img/mswa/inline-packaging.svg"/>
            </div>
            <div class="title text-poppins">
                <p>We use minimal packaging</p>
                <p>{great for the planet}</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
            <div class="icon">
                <img src="/img/mswa/inline-quality.svg"/>
            </div>
            <div class="title text-poppins">
                <p>We only choose quality</p>
                <p>{better for your health}</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
            <div class="icon">
                <img src="/img/mswa/inline-community.svg"/>
            </div>
            <div class="title text-poppins">
                <p>We love giving back</p>
                <p>{great for our community}</p></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


.did-you-know {
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

.did-you-know .items .icon {
    padding: 50px;
}
.did-you-know .items .title {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a solution:
Replace images by your images.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 5px;
}

/* Clearfix (clear floats) */
.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://freesvg.org/img/cartoonsun.png" alt="Snow" style="width:100%">
    <p style='text-align: center;'>test1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://freesvg.org/img/cartoonsun.png" alt="Forest" style="width:100%">
        <p style='text-align: center;'>test2</p>

  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://freesvg.org/img/cartoonsun.png" alt="Mountains" style="width:100%">
    <p style='text-align: center;'>test3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://freesvg.org/img/cartoonsun.png" alt="Mountains" style="width:100%">
    <p style='text-align: center;'>test3</p>
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```